# Embedding of $SO(3)$ into $S_{\infty}$

Tags: group-theory

This is a nice question which I don't have any clue.

Let $S_{\infty}$ be the group of all permutations of $\mathbb{N}.$

> Is it possible to embed $SO(3)$ into $S_{\infty}?$

Comment: Found a paper that claims that the answer is yes: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm164/fm16412.pdf

Comment: Since $SO(3)$ is simple, it is sufficient to prove that it has a subgroup of countable index. No idea how to do that though.

Comment: Dear @Dan Shved, that paper is great! you should write it as an answer.

Comment: Am I missing something here...if $G$ is an infinite group then does $G$ not embed into $S_{|G|}$? Or do you have to go up a cardinal?

Comment: @user1729: No need to go up a cardinal, but $|SO(3)| = |\mathbb{R}|$, not $|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: @Martin Ah, of course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, as proved in this paper:

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm164/fm16412.pdf